# PyCharm runs code differently when in debug mode

Tags: django, django-forms, pycharm, python-3.4

I am developing a django app , and in a view, I have the following lines:

```
form = EventRegistration(request.POST, request.FILES)
cd = form.clean()
cd['creator'] = request.user.userInfo.superUserInfo
instance = Event.objects.create(**cd)
```

which gets a form from the request and creates an object from the form (it's a modelform. )Now, when in pycharm's debug mode, when I put break points on all these lines, the program runs correctly but when I run the server normally I get this error:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: event_event.start_date
```

my Event model contains a field named start_date, which I fill correctly in the form. somehow , it fails to clean the form correctly when not in debug mode (when there is no breakpoint on the second line of code that I wrote above)

I searched the internet , but did not find anything useful.

Thanks for your help :)

Edit:

I am using django 1.8 and python 3.4

Comment: Totally unrelated but if using a ModelForm, you'd better use `instance = form.save(commit=False); instance.creator = request.user.userInfo.superUserInfo; instance.save();`. Oh and yes: check if the form is valid too...

Comment: Thanks! I will do that! but still, I need to find out what the problem is with my pycharm :(